# expectation calculation in probability and statistics

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

2 four-sided dice are rolled.

```
X = number of odd dice
Y = number of even dice
Z = number of dice showing 1 or 2
```

So each of X, Y, Z only takes on the values 0, 1, 2.

(a)  joint p.m.f. of (X,Y),  joint p.m.f. of (X,Z).

You can give your answers in the form of 3 by 3 tables.

(b) Are X and Y independent? Are X and Z independent?

(c) Compute E(XY ) and E(XZ).

WHAT I TRIED IS -

The faces on a four-sided die are labeled with the numbers 1, 2, 3, and 4. Upon throwing the dice, each one will land with exactly one of its faces upwards. You will therefore see two numbers, one for each die. Suppose, for the sake of example, that you see a 2 and a 4. Both of these are even numbers. None of them are odd numbers. Let's count: no dice show an odd number, two dice show even numbers, and one die shows a number in the set {1,2}. Therefore, for this throw,, X=0, Y=2, and Z=1.

There are 16 combinations (1,1) (1,2)(1,3) (1,4)(2,1)(2,2)(2,3)(2,4) ... (4,1 )(4,2 )(4,3 )(4,4 )

There are only 2 case when no dice show an odd number, two dice show even numbers, and one die shows a number in the set {1,2}. ---> when (2,2) (2,4 ) occurs. Here X= 0, Y =2, Z =1

Both odd and one is in {1,2} is --> (1,1)(1,3)(3,1) Here, X= 2, Y =0, Z =1
Just as we have to in the case with one discrete random variable, in order to find the "joint probability distribution" of X and Y, we first need to define the support of X and Y.

X, Y and Z combinations are - 
$$\left\{\raise{5ex}{(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), \\(2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4),\\ (3,1), (3,2), (3,3), (3,4), \\(4,1), (4,2), (4,3), (4,4)}\right\}$$

Out of this, the X, Y, Z values are  respectively,

$${(2,0,1) , (1,1,2) , (2,0,1),(1,1,1),\\(1,1,2),(0,2,1),(1,1,1),(0,2,1),\\(2,0,1),(1,1,1),(2,0,0),(1,1,0),\\(1,1,1),(0,2,1),(1,1,0),(0,2,0)}$$

b)
The random variables X and Y are independent if and only if:
P(X= x, Y = y) = P(X = x) × P(Y = y)
for allx∈S1,y∈S2.

if we again take a look back at the representation of our joint p.m.f. in tabular form, you might notice that the following holds true:
P(X=x,Y=y)
for allx∈S1,y∈S2. When this happens, we say that X and Y are independent.

Similarly for X, Z, they are also independent.

c) I am not sure how to do

help please.

Comment: Tetrahedral (four-sided) dice don't roll very well at all, but when they do land, the outcome is usually defined as the face on the bottom. There is no face on top or upwards! Also, what is meant by "support" and why is the support of $X$ the set $\{2,4\}$ when $X$ is the _number of dice_ that are "showing" an _odd-numbered_ face, and you said, quite correctly, that $X$ takes on values $0$, $1$ and $2$?  Either both dice show even-numbered faces ($X=0$) or one is odd and the other even ($X=1$) or both are even ($X=2)$. Furthermore, $X+Y=2$ always which casts doubt on the proof of independence.

Comment: @DilipSarwate  I am actually confused. I guess i am not correct in my understanding, can you help.

Comment: There are $16$ equally likely outcomes for the two dice. Make a table with first column having entries $(1,1)$ through $(4,4)$ on $16$ rows. In the second and third columns, list the values of $X$ and $Y$ for each of the $16$ outcomes.  Are there $X$ and $Y$ values _other_ than $0 ~ 2$, $1~1$, and $2~0$ in the table? Can you figure out $P(X=x,Y=y)$ for all choices of $x$ and $y$ in the set $\{0, 1, 2\}$? If so, congratulations! You have found the joint pmf of $X$ and $Y$ and all that remains is to write down the pmf in a $3\times 3$ table with rows and columns marked $0~1~2$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate yes i think i have done that, just needed help with b and c

Comment: Add a column for $Z$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Done with a , could you suggest anything for b and c , are they correct?

Answer (score 1):

The answers should probably be

For $X$ and $Y$:

(a)

$$\boxed{\begin{array}{c|ccc} X \backslash Y &  0 & 1 & 2 \\[1ex]\hline 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/4 \\[1ex] 1 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\[1ex] 2 & 1/4 & 0 & 0\end{array}}$$

(b) they are not independent: e.g. $\Bbb P(X{=}0,Y{=}0)=0 \ne \tfrac{1}{16} = \Bbb P(X{=}0)\;\Bbb P(Y{=}0)$

(c) $\Bbb E(XY) = 0\times 2 \times \tfrac{1}{4}+1\times 1 \times\tfrac{1}{2}+ 2\times 0 \times\tfrac{1}{4}=\tfrac{1}{2}$.

---

For $X$ and $Z$:

(a)

$$\boxed{\begin{array}{c|ccc} X\backslash Z & 0 & 1 & 2 \\[1ex] \hline 0 & 1/16 & 1/8 & 1/16\\[1ex] 1 & 1/8 & 1/4 & 1/8\\[1ex] 2 & 1/16 & 1/8 & 1/16\end{array}}$$

(b) they are independent: e.g. $\Bbb P(X{=}0,Z{=}0)= \tfrac{1}{16} = \Bbb P(X{=}0)\,\Bbb P(Z{=}0)$ and you can test the others

(c) $\Bbb E(XZ)= 1$ by doing the multiplications and sum, or using independence to have $\Bbb E(XZ)= \Bbb E(X)\,\Bbb E(Z)$.

Comment: @Graham Kemp: Thank you for showing off your MathJax skills